# Sending object list with Retrofit 2.0 POST

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I have a list of records and need to send to the server via POST, I use Retrofit 2.0 to make requests. I can make all requests, but I want to send the List for the server and can not.

my interface:

```
private interface SalesService{

   @POST(API_BASE + "/registrar")
   Call<List<Registro>> sendRegisters(@Body List<Registro> list);

}
```

Method send of Records:

```
public void senRegisters(List<Registro> registros) throws IOException {
    SalesService service = requestApi.create(SalesService.class);
    Call call = service.sendRegisters(registros);
    call.execute().body();
}
```

I am running sendRegister() method on a IntentService.

The server side was created using PHP Framework Slim. The method that received the request is:

```
$app->group('/api/escolas', function() use ($app){
    //recebe registros das turma e salva no banco de dados
    $app->post('/registrar', function() use ($app){
        $request = $app->request;
        $registros = json_decode($request->getBody());
        foreach($registros as $reg){
            $class = $reg->turma;
            $count = $reg->qtdAlunos;
            $app->db->insertRegister($count, $class);
        }
        exit;
    });
});
```

How to send a list of objects using retrofit?